# How to add css class from css file to a js variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have color-switcher css files.It contains css classes.The class are for colors.

Like this:

color-2.css:

```
/* Template Color Default  #ff6600 = rgba(255, 102, 0, */

/* TEXT COLOR */
nav.navbar.bootsnav.menu-style1 ul.dropdown-menu.megamenu-content .title,
.upcoming-event .clock.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn,
.pagination>li>a,
.fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-prev,
.fancybox-gallery-slider .owl-next,
.team-icon a,
.twitter.style2 ul li a,
.inner-conraimer-details h1,
.text-thm2 {
  color: #ff6600 !important;
}
```

I must add these css classes to a js variable and access this js variable from a js file.

I have below js code:

```
 if (Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
                document.querySelector(".ulockd-btn-white").classList.add("mystyle");

                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .colorful-buton-class > * > * > [role=button] { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:cyan!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

                return false;
            });

            $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "pink", "important");



                document.querySelector(".ulockd-btn-white").classList.add("mystyle");

                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.type = 'text/css';
                style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  orange!important ; }  .colorful-buton-class > * > * > [role=button] { background-color:  orange!important ; }  .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:orange!important; }  ';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);


                return false;
            });

        }


    });
```

there are some css classes in this js class:

```
 style.innerHTML = '.cssClass:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; } .colorful-buton-class:hover { background-color:  cyan!important ; }  .title-bottom:before {background-color: red!important; } .mt-separator::before, .mt-separator:before, .mt-separator::after {background-color: red!important; } .ulockd-btn-thm2:hover { background-color:cyan!important; } .wpforms-form button[type=submit]:hover { background-color:cyan!important; } .elementor-icon, .elementor-heading-title { color:red!important; }  ';
```

I must add the css file content to this variable.

how can I do it?

you can use jquery.

I am new at js and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all styles as classes in one css file. Then, import that css file to HTML file. Don't put styles inside JS. So, your all style classes will be in one css file. Then, you can add style classes you want in click functions separately. You can use following code to add class.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.classList.add("your_style_class");
```

Comment: how can I add url instead of "your_style_class"?

Comment: you have to add class name there.

Comment: can you edit your question to give a full example for me;*

Comment: you have got into unnecessary complexity in code. Refer this link. https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/html5-and-css3/how-to-use-an-external-style-sheet-for-html5-and-css3-programming/ Put classes for styles and add the classes for elements using JS as in the answer.

Comment: so your message doesnt match to my answer

Comment: Can you tell me why you are adding a style element using JS?

Comment: I need transfer its classes to js variable

Comment: You need to transfer classes in css to a js variable? If so, you have to add it to js variable manually. Why you are adding all classes to one variable?